# Asp.net Facebook webhook Updates

Tags: facebook, asp.net-web-api, webhooks

I have created a Test Ad lead and I am trying to create webhook to consume real time updates. I was able to create a webhook sucessfully but when I try to create a Test lead my webhook is not triggering and I get Error code as 301

Below is my code:

```
[HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        CreaetLogFile("Log_get");
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Content = new StringContent(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["hub.challenge"]);
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain");
        return response;
        //return  Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["hub.challenge"]);
    }

    // POST api/values
  [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
  public void Post()
  {

      // Do something
      CreaetLogFile("Log_post");
  }
```

I do not even see any post request being sent by facebook.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was my URL was not secured. Installed certificates and now I am able to receive updates